# A queuing problem related to the marriage algorithm.

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, queueing-theory

Say we have an $n\times n$ matrix and for every entry $a_{ij}$, it equals $1$ if flight $j$ starts after flight $i$ ends.  Otherwise it is $0$.  Suppose the largest matching contains $M$ marriages (i.e. $1$'s in $n\times n$ matrix is covered by $M$ lines.)

I was told from the textbook that an airline can make $n$ flights with $n-M$ airplanes except I'm having trouble seeing that.  Additionally how do you prove that we cannot have less than $n-M$?

Comment: Can you explain more explicitly say what the definitions of matching and cover are?

Comment: covered means crossed out.  So you draw M lines across rows/columns in order to eliminate all the ones in the matrix.  Matching means having a 1 entry somewhere in the matrix.  In other words if row i column j has a 1 then it means that there's a match.  between planes i and j as defined in the first sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Assume we have fixed some minimum cover with $M$ rows or columns. If the $i$-th row $A_{i \cdot}$ is chosen to be in the minimum cover, then there is some $j$ such that $a_{ij}=1$ but the $j$-th column is not chosen to be in the minimum cover. We take some such $j$, and assign it to $i$ or more precisely to $A_{i \cdot}$, say $\phi(i):=j$. We also do such assignment for each column member of the minimum cover. In arranging the airlines, we can use one airline for both $i$ and $\phi(i)$. By our definition/property of $\phi(i)$, we can use just $n-M$ airlines.

Comment: do you know how to show the second part?

Comment: Sure, I know how to show the other direction, just easy if you have the ability to understand well the structure of the scheduling matrix